# Content Security Policy issue in google recaptcha v2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, recaptcha, content-security-policy

I have searched many question on SO related to this. But nothing solves my issue.
I am using google recaptcha v2 in an asp.net mvc5 app. It works fine in google chrome. But it is showing some error in firefox and edge browsers. I suspect this as something related to content security policy headers.

**Error in Firefox**

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified

Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified

Content Security Policy: Ignoring “http:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
```

**Error in Edge**

> Security of a sandboxed iframe is potentially compromised by allowing script and same origin access.

Due to this error recaptcha is not working since it get timed out everytime

I've tried to add csp headers like this in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js https://www.gstatic.com" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

But this doesn't work as well as my page got broken since all other files got blocked by the browser

Comment: I don't believe any of the Firefox "errors" you listed would cause the script not to work. Does the script work if you remove CSP entirely?

Comment: @StephenR I am not adding any csp headers by myself. csp headers are not present in my document rather they are in the iframe created by the recaptcha

Comment: And if i remove the recaptcha script reference the errors disappear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn’t appear that the script’s failure is CSP related. Those aren’t really errors you’re getting; merely notices.

In CSP some policies override other policies, so you get a notice that policy A is ignored because you’re using policy B. So why put policy A in at all, you ask?  For compatibility with older browsers that don’t understand policy B.

For example: I use CSP nonces, but also put in “unsafe-inline”. IE doesn’t understand nonces so it uses the “unsafe-inline” rule. Modern browsers ignore the “unsafe-inline” and use the nonces.  In Firefox console I get a notice similar to what you’re getting

Comment: Ok. But can you have any idea why the recaptcha is not working in firefox and Edge. When a user clicks It is spinning forever

Comment: I would ve gone in a misdirection if you wouldn't intervene. thanks